# docker volume plugin not properly detected by docker engin

Tags: docker

I'm trying to write a docker volume plugin in Go using the `go-plugin-helpers`.

Basically I'm trying to reference `docker-volume-keywhiz` and make something simpler.

My driver seems to be working with `docker volume create -d mydriver -o foo=bar myvolume` - a new volume is created successfully and it can be mounted into a container. However, I am confused about the following facts:

1. `docker plugin ls` shows empty list. `docker info` doesn't show my plugin either. `docker volume inspect myvolume` shows the volume driver as `local` instead of `mydriver`.
2. I return a specific host path with the `Mount()` call - assuming that it'll be mapped to the path inside the container. But docker ignores it and uses `/var/lib/docker/bla`.

Also, the source code I found, including `keywhiz`, cannot be cleanly build against the latest docker API. If there is a working sample driver, please recommend.